# Flea3 USB3 camera and camera1394 package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working with Firewire cameras on my Mac using camera1394 package. Now I decided to switch to Point Grey Flea3 USB3 cameras. I remember a year ago I have read that these cameras support IIDC and that time I was able to capture images from these cameras using libdc1394 (without ROS). Now I am struggling running it with ROS camera1394 package. My questions,

(a) Did somebody use these cameras with libdc1394, without Flycapture (maybe in Linux, better in OSX)?

(b) I cannot find Flea3 GUID, that camera1394 requires. Do USB3 cameras have GUIDs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90586/flea3-usb3-camera-and-camera1394-package/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-10-16**:
We are using Chameleon, has GUID and works, but that is USB2. I had to make an udev rule to add it to plugdev group.

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-16**:
Thanks for reply, I managed to make it run on OSX. There are still some things that I am not happy with, such as delay. Will test everything then write the answer.

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2015-11-11**:
I also got a Chameleon Point Gray camera to work in OS X via libdc1394. The problem is that I can't figure out how to set the camera mode for it to give me color in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to rebuild libdc1394 library. Here is what I did,

1. downloaded latest version of the library, libdc1394-2.2.
2. added vendors and products codes to usb_products[] that is defined in libdc1394-2.2/dc1394/usb/control.c
   For flea 3, I added these two lines
   { 0x1e10, 0x3000 },
   { 0X1e10, 0x3006 },
   Finally the structure looks as follows

   /* This is the list of USB vendor/products that we know support

   - IIDC-over-USB.  Currently, this is the only mechanism of detecting
   - such cameras. */
     static struct _vendor_product_t {
     uint16_t vendor;
     uint16_t product;
     } usb_products[] = {
     { 0x1e10, 0x2000 }, // Point Grey Firefly MV Color
     { 0x1e10, 0x2001 }, // Point Grey Firefly MV Mono
     { 0x1e10, 0x2002 }, // Point Grey High Res Firefly MV Color
     { 0x1e10, 0x2003 }, // Point Grey High Res Firefly MV Mono
     { 0x1e10, 0x2004 }, // Point Grey Chameleon Color
     { 0x1e10, 0x2005 }, // Point Grey Chameleon Mono
     { 0x1e10, 0x3000 }, // Point Grey Flea 3
     { 0X1e10, 0x3006 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 Color
     { 0, 0 },
     };
3. Rebuild libdc
4. Build and run the following code that will allow you to get GUID. Later this GUID should be put to camera yaml file to run camera1394.

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdint.h>
   #include <dc1394/dc1394.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <inttypes.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   FILE* imagefile;
   dc1394camera_t *camera;
   unsigned int width, height;
   dc1394video_frame_t *frame=NULL;
   //dc1394featureset_t features;
   dc1394_t * d;
   dc1394camera_list_t * list;
   dc1394error_t err;

   ```
    d = dc1394_new ();
    if (!d)
        return 1;
    err=dc1394_camera_enumerate (d, &list);
    DC1394_ERR_RTN(err,"Failed to enumerate cameras");

    if (list->num == 0) {
        dc1394_log_error("No cameras found");
        return 1;
    }

    camera = dc1394_camera_new (d, list->ids[0].guid);
    if (!camera) {
        dc1394_log_error("Failed to initialize camera with guid %llx", list->ids[0].guid);
        return 1;
    }
    dc1394_camera_free_list (list);

    printf("Using camera with GUID %" PRIx64"\n", camera->guid);

   dc1394_video_set_transmission(camera, DC1394_OFF);
   dc1394_capture_stop(camera);
   dc1394_camera_free(camera);
   dc1394_free (d);
   return 0;
   ```

   }

It is useable now, although there are some issues with setting different modes and reducing the delay. I don't have these issues on a Windows virtual machine when I use FlyCapture.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abettadapur](https://answers.ros.org/users/8291/abettadapur/) on 2013-10-30**:
I built this code and followed this rebuilding of the library, but the library can't find my Flea3 camera. Do you have any ideas about this?

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-30**:
What camera you have and what system you are on? What is your cameras vendor and product numbers?

**Comment by [abettadapur](https://answers.ros.org/users/8291/abettadapur/) on 2013-10-31**:
Ubuntu 12.04 Flea3 Color. Flycap can recognize the camera, but this script cannot. I'll get the vendor/product numbers in a sec

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-11-01**:
If your vendor number and product number is not listed in the structure in libdc1394-2.2/dc1394/usb/control.c you have to add it. Then you can also try to install coriander (sudo apt-get install coriander) and see if you can get access to the camera through it.